# How to order and count get_terms by specific post type?

Tags: terms

I want to get a list of taxonomy "company" terms which have a particular meta value and which are associated with posts of custom type "viewpoint".

Beginning with getting Viewpoint posts, as per [recent answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/324441/get-terms-but-with-additional-dimensions?noredirect=1#comment478903_324441), WordPress' `get_posts()` supports populating the resulting array with a `fields` value of only post `ids`...

```
$vp_post_args = array(
  'post_type' => $post_type,
  'fields' => 'ids',
  'nopaging'  => 'true',
);
$viewpoint_posts = get_posts($vp_post_args);
```

Thus, `$viewpoint_posts` contains only a list of `'viewpoint'` post IDs. This list can then be used to feed a `get_terms()` call that is further constrained by `'taxonomy'   => 'company'` and a related `'meta_query'`...

```
// 2a. Get Companies matching Tag
$vp_org_term_args_for_shortlist = array(
    // Load Viewpoint post IDs in to get_terms():
    'object_ids' => $viewpoint_posts,
    // Only get Company terms
    'taxonomy'   => 'company',
    // Only company terms with Tags Checkbox value:
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key'       => 'tags',
            'value'     => $tag_section,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
         )
    ),
    // Order
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'order'      => 'desc',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    // Number of companies to show in list
    'number'     => 11,
);
$viewpoint_org_terms_for_shortlist = get_terms($vp_org_term_args_for_shortlist);
```

So far, so good. This all works.

My problem is around the `get_terms` parameter `'orderby'    => 'count'`. You see, `count` above denotes a term's total post count of **any** post type. In my case, my `'company'` taxonomy is in use by more than one post type, but here I only want to be dealing with posts of type `'viewpoint'`.

**How do I get `get_terms()` to only think within the context of a particular post type?** After all, I have already taken the step of feeding it IDs of posts which all had the same post type.

Here is my current output part...

```
// List organisations:
echo '<div class="list-group list-unstyled">';
foreach ($viewpoint_org_terms_for_shortlist as $org_short_single) {
     echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $org_short_single ) ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $org_short_single->name ) ) . '" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">';
     echo '<span><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='.get_field( 'domain', $org_short_single ).'" class="mr-2">' . $org_short_single->name . '</span>';
     echo '<span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">'.$org_short_single->count.'</span>';
     echo '</a>';
}
echo '</div>';
```

But I want to both:

- order my `company` terms list by associated number of `viewpoint` posts (not by posts of all types).
- output a post `count` for said `company` term that is post type `viewpoint`-specific (not `$org_short_single->count`, which again encompasses **all** posts)

Comment: Is the `get_terms_orderby` filter useful here? If so, I'm not sure of the particular formulation, or whether the filter would commit me to using that filter formulation every time.